# In Spring, how can I block access to a path based on a property in my UserDetails object?

Tags: spring, spring-security, controller

I’m using Spring 3.2.11.RELEASE, Spring Security 3.1.4.RELEASE but can upgrade the Spring security module if that solves my problem.  In my UserDetails object, I have the below property …

```
public class MyAuthenticationUser implements UserDetails, CredentialsContainer
{
    …
    public boolean isSampleUser()
    {
        return isSampleUser;
    }   // isSampleUser
```

Then I have a controller, which looks like

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/basedir")
public class basedirController
{

    @RequestMapping(value = “/page1”, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView doGetPDResources(final Model model,
                                         final Principal principal) throws IOException
    {
    …
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = “/page2”, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView doGetPDCenter(final Model model, final HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException
    {
        return new ModelAndView("basedir/pdcenter");
    }

…
```

What is the easiest way to block access to every method matching the URL pattern “/context-path/basedir/**” if the “isSampleUser” property of my UserDetails object evaluates to true?  Do I have to hard-code logic into every method of my controller to check for this property (seems like there is a slicker way to solve this problem that that)?

Comment: Why not use Spring Security's built-in ROLE system?

Comment: Why don't you use ROLEs?

Comment: Sadly that is not an option in our situation.  You could have two users with the same role, but one is a sample suer and the other is not and we only wish to restrict access to the user with the "isSampleUser" property = true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have suggested, it seems like you should be able to do this with roles.

For example, if isSampleUser is true you could ensure that `ROLE_SAMPLE` is part of the roles. Assuming the other role in question is `ROLE_USER`, you can then add the following rule:

```
<http ... use-expressions="true">
    ...
    <intercept-url pattern="/base-dir/**" 
                   access="hasRole('ROLE_USER') and !hasRole('ROLE_SAMPLE')"/> 
    ...
</http>
```

If you are using Java Configuration, then it would look like:

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        ...
        .antMathers("/base-dir/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER') and !hasRole('ROLE_SAMPLE')")
        ...
```

If you really don't want to add another role, you can do something like:

```
<http ... use-expressions="true">
    ...
    <intercept-url pattern="/base-dir/**" 
                   access="principal.sampleUser ? denyAll : hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/> 
    ...
</http>
```

This states that for the URL that starts with /`base-dir/**` if sampleUser returns true, then deny access otherwise the `ROLE_USER` is required.